# Primary key (two columns) identity increment

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ddl, seed

I have two columns in my primary key (id, type), id is identity and type is foreign key. 
I want to set seed for id column like following:

```
 id    type
10000   1
10001   1
10000   2
10001   2
10002   1
10002   2
10000   3
```

I could do this from code (or dml), but wonder is it possible in ddl or SqlServer table properties?

Comment: Have you some limitations on using triggers? If not you can use one instead of identity column.

Comment: Within a single type, are you allowed to have gaps in the sequence?

Comment: There's really no support for this in the **current** version of SQL Server, but with SQL Server 2012 ("Denali"), you will be able to create `SEQUENCE` objects in your DB, which would be perfect for this - they hand out sequential numbers, totally separate of any other DB objects.

Comment: @marc_s I'm not sure that SEQUENCE works for this particular purpose. In the case of the OP, you would need to create sequence for each of 10000, 10001, 10002 etc and this is impractical. You won't be able to fill in the type column just off one sequence or even a set number of sequences. You would need to create a new one every time your id column increases

Answer (score 2):

An id column increments by 1 for each row. There is no way to have it repeat. Any reason why you can't just have the identifier column be the pk for the table? You may have to resort to using a trigger to do this.

Comment: about reason: well, i argued with my team about this. the organization has several invoice types (incoming, incoming own costs, incoming advance payment, ... - proscribed by law). for ~20 years, each type number starts with the same number and i'm not sure to change this or not.

Comment: It's unclear whether you have flexibility to change table structure but in this situation I would always advocate using a surrogate key, such as InvoiceId as an identity column, and then use another column for the natural key. In this case the natural key could be InvoiceNo, which would be a combination of your id+type fields (eg. 10001-2, 10003-1). You could still have the separate column for type. If you set things up this way it doesn't matter if the business changes their mind about how invoice numbers are generated.

Comment: Smells like a normalization/database design issue. There should be a table for invoices and a table for invoice types. While the invoice can have a type column, it may not need to be part of the pk. +1 for surrogate key suggestion Clint. This is how these issues are handled in the data warehouse. Create a new identity column for the surrogate key and put a unique constraint on your old id and type columns.

Comment: @ClintGood - if I understood, you suggest following: InvoiceId identity, NaturalInvoiceId (InvoiceId+type), type FK? in this case i'm not allowed to have for example 10001-2 and 10001-3 as NaturalInvoceId. Maybe I should set NaturalInvoiceId independently of InvoiceId (increment last NaturalInvoiceId dependent of type)

Comment: It seems in your case you probably need a composite natural key. That being the case I would agree you should set NatualInvoiceId independently of InvoiceId.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server does not allow you to add or alter an Identity on an existing column via TSQL very easily. To change the original seed value and reseed any existing rows, you must drop the identity column and recreate it specifying the new seed value. When the table contains data, the identity numbers are added to the existing rows with the specified seed and increment values.